# Bash - stripping of the last digits of a number - which one is better in terms of semantic?

Tags: bash

Consider a this string containing an integer

```
nanoseconds=$(date +%s%N)
```

when I want to strip off the last six characters, what would be semantically better?

Stripping just the characters off the string

```
nanoseconds=$(date +%s%N)

milliseconds=${nanoseconds%??????}
```

or dividing the value by 1000000

```
milliseconds=$((nanoseconds / 1000000))
```

**EDIT**

Sry for not being clear. It's basically for doing a conversion from nanoseconds to milliseconds. I think I answered my own question...

Comment: Why do you need it? Is the purpose really just "stripping last three characters"?

Comment: The division requires conversion from string to number (twice), division, and conversion back to string.  Stripping 6 digits off the end involves no conversions; it should be quicker, therefore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are equivalent, but *in general* I would consider the former method to be safer. The first method is explicit and does *precisely* what you want to do: to remove a substring from the back of the string.

The other one is a mathematical operation that relies on correct rounding. Although I cannot imagine where it would fail, I would prefer the first method.

Unless, of course, what you *really* want is not stripping the last three characters but dividing by 1000 :-)

Post scriptum: hah, of course I know where it would fail. Let value="123". `${value%???}` strips the last three digits, as intended, leaving an empty string. `$(( value / 1000 ))` results in value equal to `"0"` (a string of length of 1).

EDIT: since we know now that it is not about stripping characters, but rounding, clearly dividing by 1000 is the correct way of approaching the problem :-)

Comment: Also, you should consider what to do with values like `12`.

Answer (score 1):

The clearest method when strings are involved is probably string subscription in shells that support it.

```
s=$(LC_TIME=C date +%s.%N) s=${s::-3}
```

Fortunately it appears GNU date at least defaults to zero-padding for %N, so division should be reliable. (note that both of these methods are truncation, not rounding).

```
(( s=(10#$(LC_TIME=C date +%s%N))/1000 ))
```

If you want to round, you can do a bit better than these using `printf`

```
printf -v milliseconds %.6f "$(LC_TIME=C date +%s.%N)"
```

ksh93's printf supports `%N` so there's no need for date. The conversion can be automatic. If you have (a modern) ksh available you should definitely use it.

```
typeset -T MsTime=(
    typeset -lF6 .=0

    function get {
        ((.sh.value=$(LC_TIME=C printf '%(%s.%N)T')))
    }
)

MsTime milliseconds
print -r "$milliseconds"
```